# ios development/distribution certificate - missing private key

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

I accidentally deleted private keys and my iOS certificates from the keychain Access.

So i revoked my certificates from the iOS member center and creates new ones (with new CSR) plus new provisioning profile for my app and downloaded them.

in Xcode when i try to sign the app with the new provisioning profile its marked as ineligible and my new certificate is missing private key.
[image]

[image]

Any idea to fix this problem can i match a private key manually ?

Answer (score 0):

I probably screwed up the Keychain Access on my MacBook when I accidentally deleted some of the items from there. I was not able to create the archive (.ipa) for ad-hoc distribution purpose because the certificates were not error-free (were not trusted, in red text). I repeated the steps without success - such as clicking "Request a Certificate from Certificate Authority" and creating new development and distribution certificates/profiles, deleting files from /Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles folder, /Users/owner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData folder.

I then -

(1) deleted all the keys and certificates that I had created before,

(2) downloaded the "Intermediate Signing Certificate" by clicking the link (see below), and double clicked this certificate to install it on the login keychain,

(3) I then followed the normal steps (i.e. clicking "Request a Certificate from Certificate Authority", then using this to create new development and distribution certificates, and then corresponding provisional profiles from my developer portal).

Now the certificates are free from errors (now have green check marks on the Keychain). I can now successfully make the archive (.ipa file) for distribution. Hope this helps.

P.S. My desktop Mac was fine all along, only my MacBook was screwed up.
P.S. Do not worry about the yellow warning signs on com.apple.kerberos.kdc and com.apple.systemdefault certificates found in the System keychain that said "This certificate has not been verified by a third party."

[image: Intermediate Signing Certificate]